# Modifying local intranet settings of users

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, internet-explorer

I have to create a domain policy that will add an intranet site to Local Intranet zone of domain users. I know this can be done with Internet Explorer 7 but I can't set it with IE8 and IE9. Can someone please help me, what are my options?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you attempted creating an Automatic Configuration File to push out through group policy? What type of domain are you running (2003/2008)?

Comment: It is a Windows Server 2008 R2 domain. Are you sure that it works with Internet Explorer 8 and 9? And how can I do that Automatic Configuration stuff, is there a documentation for that? Thanks!

Comment: [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc817584.aspx) is your friend. Under each of the Internet Explorer sections (hopefully my link takes you directly to the IE area), you want to look for anything about "Deployment" or the "Internet Explorer Administration Kit" (IEAK). Each version of IE has one released close to or at the same time. I've used it before and it's handy. If I remember correctly, you can set your browser to how it needs to be and it can pull the config from there.

Comment: No problem - glad I could help!